# Regex assertions working only in lookahead and lookbehind fashion

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, raku

While trying to come up with some examples for [solving this issue](https://github.com/perl6/doc/issues/2009), I came up with this snippet:

```
my regex key {^^ <![#-]> \d+ }
say "333" ~~ &key;                         # OUTPUT: «｢333｣␤»
say "#333" ~~ &key;

say '333$' ~~ m/ \d+ <?[$]>/;              # OUTPUT: «｢333｣␤»
say '333' ~~ m/ \d+ <?[$]>/;
say '$333' ~~ m/<?[$]> \d+ /;
```

only the statements indicated return `｢333｣`, which seems to indicate `<! >` works as lookahead assertion, while `<? >` works only as zero-width lookbehind. Is that the case? If that's the case, what's the way of creating a positive look-ahead assertion and a negative look-behind?

Comment: Fwiw, your examples all seem to do what I'd expect them to do -- I'm not seeing any problem. You write "`<! >` works as lookahead assertion". Yes, a negative lookahead zero width assertion. You write "`<? >` works only as zero-width lookbehind." I'm not seeing that. It looks to me like it's behaving like a positive lookahead zero width assertion, as I would expect. What am I missing?

Comment: When you use `!`, yo make it negative, when you use `?` you make it a positive lookaround. See [Perl6 docs](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#Lookahead_assertions). Positive lookahead: `<?before pattern>`, negative - `<!before pattern>`. Positive lookbehind: `<?after pattern>`, negative - `<!after pattern>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you've just misinterpreted your experiments.

> `<? >` works only as zero-width lookbehind. Is that the case?

No. It's a lookahead. Per your own experiments:

```
say '333$' ~~ m/ \d+ <?[$]>/;              # OUTPUT: «｢333｣␤»
```

The `\d+` matches `333`.

The `<? >` does a zero width assertion. What does it assert? It asserts, positively (`?` not `!`) that the *next* character (so it's a lookahead, like most regex patterns) must be `$`. The next character is indeed `$`, so the assertion succeeds. But as it's a zero-width assertion, it doesn't move the matching cursor forward. (That's what the "zero-width" aspect means.)

Then the overall regex is done, the overall regex succeeds, and the overall regex captures just `333`.

```
say '333' ~~ m/ \d+ <?[$]>/;
```

In this instance there is no `$` for the positive assertion to match, so the overall match fails.

```
say '$333' ~~ m/<?[$]> \d+ /;
```

As before, the `<?[$]>` asserts that the next character is a `$`. It is, so it succeeds. But, because it's a *zero-width* assertion, *it does not advance the cursor*.

The `\d+` then fails (because the matching cursor is still pointing at a `$`).